# HttpClient javadoc jar (for netbeans 7)

Tags: netbeans, httpclient, javadoc

I am looking to add the javadoc (jar) for HttpClient to my IDE (Netbeans). Has anyone actually seen the jar file? or is there another way to add javadocs to Netbeans (or Eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

To do this, the best way is to add a new library in the IDE and attach the Javadoc to this library. You can try the following steps to do this:

1. In the NetBeans IDE, go to "Tools > Libraries".
2. In the Library Manager, click at New Library and enter the data requested if the library don't exists
3. Select the library you want to add the Javadoc, and choose the Javadoc tab.
4. Click "Add ZIP/Folder" and browse to where your project Javadoc is located.
5. Specify the Javadoc ZIP or folder and click "Add ZIP/Folder".
6. Click "OK" to close the Library Manager.

More details can be found at [this NetBeans Wiki page](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqJavaDoc#Library_Manager).

Regards